# How do the Power Rangers back their operations financially?

Tags: power-rangers

Unlike Batman and Iron Man, both billionaires capable of funding any operation they like, the Power Rangers don't appear to have substantial resources. How do they back their operations financially? Running humongous robotic machines to defeat giant monsters sounds like several millions of dollars, if not billions.

Comment: By running a clandestine crystal meth operation in suburban New Mexico.

Comment: I'm not saying it was aliens, but it was aliens.

Comment: Couple things: First, what do they need financial backing for? All their gear is based on energy attacks and their gear comes from some outside alien source(s). Humanity doesn't have the ability to "morph" and grant special abilities and etc. (as far as we know). All that gear can run off one off-world/ alien battery that lasts forever. So far as we know Alpha-5 could repair the zords or they could repair themselves... there really isn't much the need financially...

Comment: But given that in the universe of Power Rangers it should be common place to see them fighting monsters and giant monsters on a regular basis it would be entirely possible the world/UN/etc. all chip in...

Comment: which iteration of the power rangers? Mighty morphin? mystic force? Light Speed Rescue? Are you asking strictly about the american version of the series or are you also asking about the super sentai?

Comment: @jneko Well I am considering the American versions only

Comment: They use the same credit card the scooby doo gang used to fund their escapades. and Bruce Wayne has agreed to pay for the collateral damage. He's a pretty stand up guy for what's basically a war lord.

Comment: The way each Ranger team works is so different you really need to be more specific. SPD is a police force from the future, so they're presumably government funded (unless it's one of those futures where corporations own the police); Andros from In Space was probably a rich kid; Zordon was apparently operating since the 1800s so he's had plenty of time to become part-owner of various major corporations.

Comment: By being part-time supervillains on another planet.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens - Under the moniker "Mighty Morphine"?

Comment: Merchandising??

Answer (score 10):

By and large, the Power Rangers teams do not need substantial financial resources.

Virtually all of the Power Rangers equipment and abilities are created or powered by the Morphing Grid, which is a universal energy field which some things are capable of tapping into.

The Zords, while seeming mechanical, do not operate as mechanical devices would.  They do not seem to require regular maintenance, they are seen to be completely changed by Morphing Grid power.

[image: Lion Thunderzord, created from the Mastadon Zord]

Given that many of the Rangers other tools are created similarly (in flashes of energy, either during morphing or post-morphing), it stands to reason that most of their gear is supplied by (and maintained by) the morphing grid itself.

Some beings, such as Zordon and Alpha 5 from the original show, are knowledgeable in the applications of the Morphing Grid energy and can harness it to specific purpose (such as the Command Center's teleporters).  It's reasonable to assume that these people are the primary source for most of the Ranger's specialty gear.

Sometimes Rangers themselves learn how to harness this ability.  Billy, for instance, created tools which let the original Rangers interface with the Command Center's existing technology.  Later, after giving up his Ranger abilities, he continued to aid the later teams by providing technical support.

Some Ranger teams are legacy teams - a good example is the Mystic Force.  They are taking over for a previous team of Rangers and learn to use the same equipment and tools which the previous team used.

By and large, the Power Rangers do not need substantial financial resources to do their superhero work.  When they do need something that the Morphing Grid does not provide, it tends to be a plot McGuffin which they can locate and secure by adventuring, not something they would have to order on Amazon.

Comment: The whole idea of the Zords and equipment coming from the Morphing Grid only applies to some teams, notably Mighty Morphin'. Depending on the series, they are also animals (Lost Galaxy, Wild Force), constructed by scientists (Lightspeed Rescue, SPD, RPM), pure magic (Mystic Force), or alien technology (In Space, Dino Charge). The answer would probably be better to clarify that it mostly just applies to Mighty Morphin' (although in fairness, the question doesn't specify either.

Comment: @Thunderforge - yes, the zords of other teams are based on other things, but all of these are enhanced by the morphing grid.  Without that power, how could the Zords change to combine?

Comment: The morphing grid is a bigger deal in some of the incarnations than others. I'm pretty sure that at least for the ones where they are constructed by scientists, they were designed to combine (and the morphing grid was not part of the explanation for how). Regardless, it's probably moot and isn't really that relevant to the original question of how the Power Rangers are financially backed.